# What is the scope of HttpServletRequest when being used in a controller (singleton)?

Tags: java, spring

I have this doubt... I have a singleton bean...and I want to set some parameters on the `HttpServletRequest`, on this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myMethod(final ModelMap model, final HttpServletRequest req){
       req.getSession().setAttribute("myKey", "someValue");
       return "/myURL";
    }
```

So, if I set myKey, that value will be accessible **only** by the current user in that session? or because it is a singleton bean could be overriden by other user?

Comment: so you are adding singleton bean to the session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the lifecycle of a HttpServlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894088/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-a-httpservlet)

Comment: I am using the controller, but by default it is singleton..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the session, not the controller. And the session is associated with the user making the request, so other users won't be able to see this value.

From [getSession() documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()):

> Returns the current session associated
>   with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates
>   one.

Comment: Also - if accessing the session you're doing anyway with the servlet request - you can just as well use put the session as a parameter for your method, e.g. public String myMethod(final ModelMap model, final HttpSession session){ ... }